# Context aware button in a listview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a Listview that pulls and displays some data.  Field 1 is the PK, Field 2 is a type identifier, and the rest are plain data.  I have a button I've made that appears as the last field on every record.  The button needs to be able to call the proper page based on Field 2, and pass it the value of Field 1.

How can I tell which record is being clicked, and grab the appropriate values for my logic?

```
|Field 1|Field 2|Button |
|      1|      2| Click |
|      2|      2| Click |
|      3|      1| Click |
```

Comment: By "calling the proper page" you mean posting back the form to that page or simply doing a `Response.Redirect`?

Comment: `Response.Redirect`.  I have the values being stored in session variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the markup of your `ListView` where you define your button, do this:

```
<asp:button id="yourButton" OnClientClick='<%#redirectToProperPage(Eval("Field1"),Eval("Field2"))%>' />
```

Now, define a JS function like so:

```
function redirectToProperPage(id1,id2)
 {
      if(id2==1)
      {
        if(id1==1)
           window.location='MyOtherpage.aspx';
        else 
          window.location='Different.aspx';
      }
      else ...
 }
```

You get the idea... you don't need code behind for this unless you want to do something more than simply redirecting to a different page.

Comment: Thanks.  I had not thought of passing a function in this manner.